# Send string gremlin query to Amazon Neptune database using TinkerPop's gremlinpython

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

We can do the following to create a connection, and then attached the connection to the graph `g` object, and then use `g` to mirror gremlin query inline.

```py
    from gremlin_python import statics
    from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
    from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
    from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
    Create a GraphTraversalSource which is the basis for all Gremlin traversals:
    
    graph = Graph()
    connection = DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g')
    g = graph.traversal().withRemote(connection)
    g.V().limit(2).toList()
```

However, I want to submit string grelmin query like below,

```py
    connection = DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g')
    
    query = "g.V().limit(2).toList()"
    connection.submit(query)
```

Then I'm getting the following error. Looks like I did NOT call the `submit()` function correctly, and I can't find any docs or examples on this function. Please help.

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'source_instructions'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/sentry_sdk/integrations/aws_lambda.py", line 152, in sentry_handler
    return handler(aws_event, aws_context, *args, **kwargs)
    response = remoteConn.submit(query)
  File "/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py", line 56, in submit
    result_set = self._client.submit(bytecode, request_options=self._extract_request_options(bytecode))
  File "/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py", line 81, in _extract_request_options
    options_strategy = next((x for x in bytecode.source_instructions
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of calling submit from Gremlin Python, you need to create the connection a slightly different way:

```py
client = client.Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g')

query = """
g.V().hasLabel('airport').
               sample(30).
               order().by('code').
               local(__.values('code','city').fold()).
               toList()
"""

result = client.submit(query)
future_results = result.all()
results = future_results.result()


client.close()
```

The full example [is here](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/basic-client.py)