# mergeV query not working on AWS Neptune with gremlinpython

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

So I'm trying to follow the instructions on this thread [Send string gremlin query to Amazon Neptune database using TinkerPop's gremlinpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400302/send-string-gremlin-query-to-amazon-neptune-database-using-tinkerpops-gremlinpy), but it's not working with the mergeV example extracted directly from AWS Neptune Docs. A simple "g.V().limit(10)" it works, though. What am I doing wrong?

I tried this:

```
from gremlin_python.driver import client
import os

# Neptune connection setup
neptune_endpoint = os.getenv('NEPTUNE_ENDPOINT')
neptune_port = os.getenv('NEPTUNE_PORT')
neptune_uri = f'wss://{neptune_endpoint}:{neptune_port}/gremlin'

conn = client.Client(neptune_uri,'g')
            
query = """
g.mergeV([(T.id): 'v-1']).
option(onCreate, [(T.label): 'PERSON', email: 'person-1@example.org', age: 21]).
option(onMatch, [age: 22]).
id()
"""

result = conn.submit(query)
results = result.all().result()

print(results)
```

and got this:

Received error message '{'requestId': '00f7a9b8-8a42-4a94-8e62-a2f28f3e2385', 'status': {'code': 499, 'message': '{"detailedMessage":"Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed at line 2, character position at 2, error message : token recognition error at: 'mer'","requestId":"00f7a9b8-8a42-4a94-8e62-a2f28f3e2385","code":"MalformedQueryException"}', 'attributes': {}}, 'result': {'meta': {}, 'data': None}}'

Comment: The query worked fine for me on Neptune. Which Amazon Neptune engine version are you using? The `mergeV` step is quite recently added to Gremlin, and requires the Neptune engine version to be at the 1.2.1.0 level or higher. Release notes are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.2.1.0.html

Comment: I'm glad it's working. I'll convert my comment to an answer in case others find this post.

Answer (score 1):

The `mergeV` step was added to Apache TinkerPop as part of the 3.6.x release line. The first Amazon Neptune engine version to support Gremlin at that level was 1.2.1.0.

Upgrading your Neptune engine version to at least that level should allow both `mergeV` and `mergeE` to work. See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.2.1.0.html